# How do i call an AS400 program from command prompt of windows?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying to call a program using command prompt using command
 
**"QUOTE RCMD CALL PGM(LIB/MyPGM)"**
I am getting this error : 
[image]

How to perform this action ?

Comment: This doesn't seem programming related.

Comment: Good point, @Charles.  Perhaps it should be moved to ServerFault.

Comment: This rcmd feature is a security hole.

Comment: You say `command prompt of windows` but instead show a FTP session. To call an IBM i program from a "command prompt of windows", you can install iSeries Access for Windows and use rmtcmd  at a command (not inside FTP). Or you might use rexec instead.

Comment: @danny117 Every server that has a method of remote command execution (i.e., Windows, UNIX/Linux, mainframe, whatever) has a `security hole`.

Answer (score 3):

try like this, with pgm

```
quote rcmd CALL PGM(YOURLIB/YOURPROG)
```

if you have arguments

```
quote rcmd CALL PGM(YOURLIB/YOURPROG) PARM('ARG1' 'ARG2')
```

Comment: This is what he did and had problems with, no? Replacing the implicit PGM() with an explicit PGM() will not make any difference.

Comment: No he didnt, look his screen copy not his text

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, your command is correct.  The error occurred while the server was trying to call the program.  The text for message CEE9901 is:

```
Message . . . . :   Application error.  &1 unmonitored by &2 at statement &5, 
  instruction &3.                                                             
Cause . . . . . :   The application ended abnormally because an exception     
  occurred and was not handled.  The name of the program to which the         
  unhandled exception is sent is &6 &8 &12. The program was stopped at the    
  high-level language statement number(s) &11 at the time the message was     
  sent.  If more than one statement number is shown, the program is an        
  optimized ILE program.  Optimization does not allow a single statement      
  number to be determined.  If *N is shown as a value, it means the real value
  was not available.                                                          
Recovery  . . . :   See the low level messages previously listed to locate the
  cause of the exception.  Correct any errors, and then try the request again.
```

So, at this point, you need to examine the iSeries job log.  To do this, you need to find your job among the different FTP jobs out there.  Execute this command (if you have the authority):

```
WRKACTJOB JOB(QTFTP*)
```

Find the job with the `Current User` set to the login you used for FTP.  Then examine the job log of that job.  You will likely see the real error that caused the CEE9901 to generate.

If you do not have authority to the WRKACTJOB command, an alternative is to print your job log and look at the resulting spooled file.  Use these FTP commands:

```
quot rcmd CHGJOB LOG(4 00 *SECLVL) LOGCLPGM(*YES)
quot rcmd DSPJOBLOG OUTPUT(*PRINT)
```

Then look in your spooled files for the QPJOBLOG.  It should go to the spooled files of whichever user you logged into FTP with.  This AS/400 command (from the green screen) will help you find it:

```
WRKSPLF SELECT(*CURRENT *ALL *ALL QTFTP*)
```

Without seeing the job log, I can't be certain of the cause.  However, most errors of this type, in my experience, are caused by missing libraries in your library list.  You may have to first execute some `ADDLIBLE` commands using the `quot rcmd` FTP command.  Like this:

```
quot rcmd addlible mypgmlib
quot rcmd addlible mydatalib
```

Followed by:

```
quot rcmd call mylib/mypgm
```

Comment: wrkusrjob   [userid your using for ftp]    is probably easier to find job than wrkactjob.

Comment: @danny117, At least on V6R1, WRKUSRJOB does not show active FTP jobs the way WRKACTJOB does.  Probably because the FTP job is running under the QTCP user profile.  This may have changed in later versions of the OS, but I don't have any handy to test that with.

Comment: I concur above is incorrect.  QTCP profile running rcmd.

Comment: @TracyProbst  I'm able to call the CL commands using **quot rcmd <command>** . Here i have one small problem. In the <command> i am trying to copy the spooled file to one of my work library using `CPYSPLF    FILE(QPDSPSTS) TOFILE(ICIWRKVN1/DSPSYSSTS)` command . If i use this command manually its getting executed as expected. But, in remote session it is trying to execute above command and hitting error "cannot find job name QPDSPSSTS" in QTCP job log.Originally 'QPDSPSSTS' spooled file will be created with another user name. how can i execute that command correctly using `Quot rcmd`

Comment: @NandanSVamc, what's the *exact* CL command in the job log before that error.  Is the command in your comment the entirety of the CL command or is there more/less to it?

Comment: @TracyProbst , Exact CL command is `CPYSPLF FILE(QPDSPSTS) TOFILE(ICIWRKVN1/DSPSYSSTS)` this gets executed when i try to give from AS400 terminal. But same command is throwing below 
**File QPDSPSTS not found in job 303622/QTCP/QTFTP00169.** error.
when trying to execute from remote using `quot rcmd CPYSPLF FILE(QPDSPSTS) TOFILE(ICIWRKVN1/DSPSYSSTS)` because it is searching for job log name 'QPDSOSTS' submitted with _QTCP_ here this job name can be found with _MYUSERNAME_ .Do i need to modify anything while running such commands? Please suggest.

Comment: What command is generating this output?  Is is being generated from the same job/program that was called from the FTP session or some other source?

Comment: @TracyProbst same job called from FTP session

Comment: If QPDSPSTS is not in job 30622/QTCP/QTFTP00169, where is it?  Are you able to find the spooled file using the green screen?  Try this command: WRKSPLF SELECT(*ALL *ALL *ALL *ALL *ALL QPDSPSTS).  I see two possibilities at this point: 1) The spooled file was not created for whatever reason. 2) The spooled file belongs to a different job.  If it's a different job, we need to discover why.

Comment: @TracyProbst its a different job. Can we gather that job dynamically , during runtime...

Comment: @NandanSVamc, it can be done, but I think we're moving beyond the scope of this Stack Overflow question.  So I suggest a new question involving how to find spooled files in other jobs. In that question, post the details and we'll try to look through it that way.  I think this question is answered, though.  You have the correct remote command call and you now know why you're getting the error.

Comment: Because the FTP server job runs under user QTCP, spooled files for the logged on user probably will not be placed under the FTP server job. Those spooled files will likely be detached and recorded under a job named QPRTJOB. It's hard to guess how many jobs might exist by that name, but WRKJOB {ftp-user}/QPRTJOB should show it in the list. Search the Knowledge Center for QPRTJOB for the many details.

Comment: @TracyProbst Ok fine thanks will post a new question and update the details here.

Comment: @TracyProbst submitted my question with details ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757520/how-to-identify-and-use-spooled-files-of-other-user-using-qtcp-usercommand-prom

Comment: @NandanSVamc, I'm actually out of commission for the next few weeks because our family just adopted a little boy from China.  I'll post a comment on your question in the hopes that someone may see it before I'm back.